# How to use a method in other class without creating a new object

Tags: java

I'm a Java beginner working on a Java GUI project.
I create my object in my TEST CLASS and write my set get function in CLASSA.
I want to use the set get function in CLASSB, but I can only use the function by creating a new object in CLASSB. It will cover my data stored in CLASSA, that I can't get anything in CLASSB.

I can't use extends because CLASSB has already extends JFrame.

Comment: What does your `CLASSB` and `CLASSA` look like right now? Can you share some code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mark `ClassA` as static, you can call `ClassA.MyFuntion()` in `ClassB` without having to create a new object.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need is to create a method of **class** in *CLASSB*, rather than of **instance**.

This is achieved by using the `static` keyword when creating the method.

```
public static void myMethod() {
  // logic here
}
```

You can take a look at [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-methods-vs-instance-methods-java/), for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Make the function a `public static` function and you can call it using `[classname].[function](value)`

heres an example. class `TestA` defines the function which is called in `TestB`

```
package test;

public class TestA {
    public static void square(int x) {
        int y=x*x;
        System.out.print(y);
    }
}
```

---

```
package test;

public class TestB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 2;
        TestA.square(x);
    }
}
```